# Wiremock encoding issue

Tags: java, character-encoding, wiremock

I'm currently trying to use wiremock to mock the result of http calls in my unit tests, and when I try to get the response body, I got some encoding issues.

I write one methode to stub a post methode

```
public static void setupMockExecutionResponse(WireMockServer mockService) throws IOException {
    mockService.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/reportExecutions"))
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE+"; charset=utf-8")
                    .withHeader("set-cookie", "JSESSIONID=1111111111111; SERVERID=jasper")
                    .withBody(
                            copyToString(
                                    JasperClientMock.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("payload/execution-response.json"),
                                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
}
```

As you can see I specified that the charset of the response body is UTF-8, and in the header I add it too.

The json file used as the response is also encoded in UTF-8

```
{
  "status":"ready",
  "totalPages":1,
  "requestId":"217f7dc9-47c4-4c44-bada-7e29b653887b",
  "reportURI":"/test/test/test/test/export_test",
  "exports":[
    {
      "status":"ready",
      "outputResource":{
        "contentType":"application/pdf",
        "fileName":"export_test.pdf",
        "outputFinal":true,
        "outputTimestamp":0
      },
      "id":"6ca0038f-94ff-4bd9-bdf4-6a35259fd05e"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect when I make the post request to get the header specified in the setUp of the mock and the json string corresponding at my file.

```
feign.Response r = jasperFeignClient.executeReport(headerMap, requestBody);
checkResponseStatut(r.status(), EXECUTION_STEP, documentJasperRequest.getUrlReport(), requestBody);
getCookie(r, cookies);
String execResponse = IOUtils.toString(r.body().asInputStream(), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

I have the good return code (200), the cookies that I set, but my response body is messed up and look like this
[image]

So when I try to convert it to a java object I have parsing error, because it can't find the begining character of the json.

I even tryed to hard code the json string directly in the body of the stub, but that didn't change a things.

---

**EDIT**
When I make a direct call to the stubbed endpoint in my test, the encoding is good

```
    @Test
    public void testGetPDF(){
        Response response = given().when().post("http://localhost:9561/reportExecutions");
        String status = response.jsonPath().get("status");
        System.out.println(status);
        assertEquals(status, "ready");
    }
```

It's only when I go into the class where the call is made that i got encoding issues.

Comment: somehow, updating all my dependenies in my pom solved this encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating all my pom dependencies to their latest version solved this encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your call via the Jasper client is by default setting `accept-encodig:gzip` (or something similar) and WireMock is therefore returning a gzipped body.

You should be able to resolve the issue by doing one of: a) disabling gzip in WireMock, b) disabling gzip in your client config, or c) ungzipping the body before attempting to parse it.